# How can I avoid TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

I am creating a program that will simulate an Nba player's statline. I am a beginner and unfortunately I have run into the following error:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'
```

This error occurs at **while numbers > 0:**

Here is my code so far:

```py
import random

Malcolm_Brogdon_tendencies = { "Under_Basket_Rate" : 396, 
"Close_Left_Rate" : 32, "Close_Mid_Rate" : 50, "Close_Right_Rate" : 38, "Mid_Left_Rate" : 6, "Mid_Mleft_Rate" : 36, "Mid_Mleft" : 375, "Mid_Mid_Rate" : 47, 
"Mid_Mright_Rate" : 83, "Mid_Right_Rate" : 15, "Three_Left_Rate" : 8, "Three_Mleft_Rate" : 91, "Three_Mid_Rate" : 70, "Three_Mright_Rate" : 109, "Three_right_Rate" : 18}

Malcolm_Brogdon_Percentages = {"Under_Basket" : 487, "Close_Left" : 571, "Close_Mid" : 515, "Close_Right" : 480, "Mid_Left" : 500, "Mid_Mleft" : 375,
 "Mid_Mid" : 452, "Mid_Mright" : 564, "Mid_Right" : 400, "Three_Left" : 0, "Three_Mleft" : 350, "Three_Mid" : 261, "Three_Mright" : 319, "Three_Right" : 417}

Malcolm_Brogdon_Person = {"Shot_Attempts" : random.randint(10,16)}

do_not_include = [0]
total_shots = 0


while total_shots< Malcolm_Brogdon_Person["Shot_Attempts"]: 
    for tendencies, numbers in Malcolm_Brogdon_tendencies.items(): 
        for numbers in Malcolm_Brogdon_tendencies.items(): 
            while numbers > 0: 
                shot_distribution = random.randint(1,1001) 
                if shot_distribution not in do_not_include: 
                    do_not_include.append(shot_distribution) 
                    total_shots = total_shots + 1 
                    numbers = numbers - 1 

            
            
print (do_not_include)
```

I also understand that it would be easier to import the data from the internet, however, I wanted to start slow. The numbers represent how many times out a 1000 each one would occur. Then for each one in `Malcolm_Brogdon_Tendencies` it would generate that many numbers out of 1000 and assign them a value so that `Close_Left_Rate`, for example would occur 32/1000 times. There is probably a much simpler way to do this, however, I am new to programming and do not know that much.

I know that the variable, numbers, is the value in `Malcolm_Brogdon_Tendencies` and cannot be compared to an int. Is there a way to parse the number before so it acts as an int?

Thank you to anyone who helps because I realize that I gave a horrible description and that my code could probably be simplified a ton.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Logically, what are you trying to compare when comparing a tuple with an int? Are you trying to check the length of the tuple?

Comment: What do you get when you do `print(numbers)` just before the line where the error occurs?

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  Don't apologize for long code -- **fix** it before you post here.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are trying to access the number part of the (key,value) pair in items so try replacing

```
while numbers > 0:
```

with

```
while numbers[1] > 0:
```

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing

```
while numbers > 0:
```

with

```
while int(numbers[0]) > 0:
```

This is way it will only compare the integer from the tuple.

Comment: `numbers[0]` will be a string.